# How to rightclick context menu open from normal Button Click in IE 11?

Tags: javascript

IN IE11 I am able to download image from right click.

I want to download from button click, how it is possible?

I am trying to write a method something like the code below but it is showing error... "Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener"

```js
function addEventListner() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('testDownload').addEventListener('click', oncontextmenu)) {
    console.log("test");
    // document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    //     console.log("You've tried to open context  menu"); //here you draw your own menu
    // })
  }
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and the function oncontextmenu

Comment: This statement does not make sense. It does not need an if `if (document.getElementsByClassName('testDownload').addEventListener('click', oncontextmenu)) {
 ` - perhaps you mean `document.getElementsByClassName('testDownload').addEventListener('click', function(e) {  console.log("test"); })`  or `document.getElementsByClassName('testDownload').addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {  console.log("test"); })`

Comment: I want context menu should call after buttonclick

Comment: Perhaps something [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+open+contextmenu+left+click+site%3Astackoverflow.com)